# I would like to pipe output of find into input list of scp, how?

Tags: linux, find, scp, pipe

I'm a novice linux user and I am trying to send a long list of files from one computer to another.  The argument list is too long, so I am using find.  I am having trouble setting up the expression, though.  Can someone help?

Here is what I would normally type for a short argument list.

```
scp ./* phogan@computer/directory...
```

Here's I think this might translate into with find.

```
scp find . -name "*" phogan@computer/directory...
```

Maybe I could use piping?  Any suggestions would help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
find . -name "*" -exec scp '{}' phogan@computer:/directory ';'
```

**Normally** I  would 'tar' all the files together into one huge blob and call 'scp' just once. Something like this:

```
tar czfv - file1 file2 dir1 dir2 | ssh phogan@computer/ tar xvzf - -C directory
```

- One could play around with the --exclude= or --include= parameters of tar.
- Another option would be to use [rsync](https://superuser.com/questions/31867/what-is-the-best-way-to-perform-daily-weekly-monthly-backups).

Comment: if using passwords with ssh/scp, wouldn't the solution with find ask for a password on every file?

Comment: lets just assume he knows how to use ssh-keys :) the problem with 1000 password questions is also the reason for the tar-approach

Comment: @akira Does your second solution involving tar looks in any way for files? how do you suggest to adapt it to include find in it and not just a bunch of predefined files like 'file1 file2 dir1 dir2'?

Answer (score 19):

You can do it with just one command `scp`.

- for newer versions of `scp`:

```bash
scp `find <path> -name <expression>` user@host:<path_where_to_copy>
```

- for older versions:

```bash
scp --exec=`find <path> -name <expression>` user@host:<path_where_to_copy>
```

Make sure to encapsulate the `find` command in between *backticks* **`** and not single quotes **'**.

Comment: Which scp version, which linux distribution it that? E.g. scp in Ubuntu 14.04 does not have this option.

Comment: Hi, older versions support it, the new versions support a simpler command: ``scp `find <path> -name <expression>` user@host:<path_where_to_copy>``

Comment: Doesn't work on multiple files

Comment: @Amruta use `-r`

Comment: @slybloty `scp -r` is for recursion on a single (directory) entry, not for multiple entries (multiple files).

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in `find . -name "*"`;do scp $f phogan@computer/directory;done
```

Comment: yea he wants a single command anyway

Comment: useful, used it with `grep -l pattern *`

Comment: Does not seem to work on files with spaces in them.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest

```
find . -print0 | tar --null --files-from=/dev/stdin -cf - | ssh phogan@computer tar -xf - -C /directory
```

Note, that this solution avoids having the filenames on the command line where they might be interpreted as command line arguments.

Another thing to watch out for is that filenames might contain spaces. This means that a for loop in bash might have difficulties with a list of filenames.